# How to send request(parameter) in jwplayer when play button is clicked

Tags: jwplayer

I want to pass (timestamp and other details) to the server when play button is clicked on jwplayer .

```
function playVideo(filename) {
 jwplayer("video").setup({
   file: filename?code=<hexCodegenerated by timestamp of request>,

    width: "80%",
});
jwplayer('video').load();
```

}

Could you please help, how to pass the generated code as queryString when play button is clicked for the first time.

Comment: Do you mean you want the actual URL of the page to update when play is pressed as well?

Comment: Not Necessary .. It should make a HTTP request to the server where content is kept, but for authentication purpose the queryString should also get appended with the hex code generated (which should contain the TimeStamp when the play button is hit) .

Comment: How do you plan on storing it. Using JS?

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work?

```
jwplayer().onPlay(function() {
var d = new Date();
alert(d.getMilliseconds()); 
alert(d.getTime());
});
```